# getReference() of doctrine Entity Manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

### Situation:

I want to use the [getReference()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L374-413) function of doctrine2 Entity Manager. However, in a situation where I ask for an object that has been deleted from the database, I obtain a proxy if I ask for that same object more than once.

### An example:

```
//A random article object...that has been deleted from the database
$articleClass = 'Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article';
$articleIdentifiers = array('id'=>1);
$i = 0;

//We ask for its reference twice
do{
    try {
        echo "a";
        $subject = $this->em->getReference(
            $subjectClass,
            $subjectIdentifiers
        );
       //call this object now
       var_dump($subject);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "b";
    }
    $i++;
} while ($i <2);
```

### The output:

```
a
b
a
object(Proxies\__CG__\Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article)
```

How can I get a proxy for an object that doesn't even exist in the database? If I comment [this line](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L410), the entityManager does not manage the object and I obtain the output `abab`, which to me makes more sense as I don't want to get a proxy object that does not exist in the database. For info, the proxy object returned has all its properties `null`. I therefore obtain a proxy for an object that does not exist in the database. So, if I ask for this object I get a "Not found Entity" exception.

### The challenge

Can anyone make any sense of this? Is there a way to rely on `getReference()` to tell us whether this object really does exist in the database?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no way to make `getReference()` check the database for the existence of the referenced object.

Actually, this is what `getReference()` and the proxies returned by it are all about: Creating placeholder objects (proxies) without going to the database. And you would rarely want to do that explicitly. Normally Doctrine does this internally when hydrating entities to create lazy loading placeholders for related entities based on foreign key values.

Why don't you just call `find()` on the Entity Manager? Are you aware that the EM will **not** query the DB more than once for the same object as long as you look it up by ID? Doctrine keeps track of already hydrated objects in the Unit Of Work and returns references to the existing objects in subsequent `find()` calls.

Comment: Actually, if you use inheritance mapping and request the reference of a parent class (i.e., one that has sub classes which are also in your discriminator map) Doctrine instantly fetches the object you're referencing ([see EntityManager::getReference():459](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L459)). It needs to do that in order to know the entity's class (because you only gave it a super class). So in this case you either get an object back from ``getReference()`` if it exists or you get ``null`` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `getReference` to get an object, but then call a method on it such as `getName` then Doctrine will fetch the entity from the DB. It has no other way to find out the property (getName).

---

**Concerning your challenge:**

`EntityManager->contains($entity)` would be the preferred way to check if the entity from doctrine is in the entity manager

Answer (score 0):

You need get reference and check if contains on database:

```
$classChild = $this->doctrine->getReference($classReference, $id);                                
if (!$this->doctrine->contains($classChild)) {
    throw new \Exception("Invalid Reference");
}
```

Where $this->doctrine is your EntityManager

Answer (score 0):

error when code:

```
$user = $this->getReference(UserFixtures::USER, User::class);

        $news1 = (new News())
            ->setHeader('news test #1')
            ->setText('news test text #1')
            ->setTimePublic('11:00')
            ->setInitiator($user)
        ;
```

success when separate setter:

```
$user = $this->getReference(UserFixtures::USER, User::class);

    $news1 = (new News())
        ->setHeader('news test #1')
        ->setText('news test text #1')
        ->setTimePublic('11:00')
    ;
    $news1->setInitiator($user);
```