# Symfony2 ObjectNormalizer denormalize callbacks

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, serialization

Is it possible to use `setCallbacks` on `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer` which are invoked when calling `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer.deserialize()` to convert a  normalized value back to an object?

I know the reverse is possible in that a object can be normalized when calling `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer.serialize()`.  I just don't how to do the reverse normalization.

Example of serialization on entity with `setCallbacks` converting `Foo` to an `Id`:

```
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
    $normalizer->setCallbacks(array(
        'foo' => function ($foo) {
            return $foo instanceof Foo
                ? $foo->getId()
                : null;
        },
    ));
    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));

    $json = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json');
```

The reverse I would Like to do:

```
$em = static::getEntityManager();

    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
    $normalizer->setCallbacks(array(
        'foo' => function ($foo) use($em) {
            return !is_null($foo)
                ? $em->getReference('\Entity\Foo', $foo)
                : null;
        },
    ));
    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));

    return $serializer->deserialize($entity, $classname, 'json');
```

The error I get:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to \Entity\Bar::setFoo() must be an instance of \Entity\Foo, integer given
```

Or is there a pre step that can be carried out before `deserialize`?

Comment: Did you ever work out how to do this?

Answer (score -3):

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456090/getreference-of-doctrine-entity-manager) to see what do exact `getReference`.

> There is no way to make `getReference()` check the database for the existence of the referenced object.

If you want to work your deserealize you must use `$em->getRepository('\Entity\Foo')->find($foo)`

Comment: I guess this answer has nothing in common with question asked.