# Doctrine entity relations not updated during same kernel request

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have two entity objects in doctrine: Product, ProductComponent. One product can have multiple components.
First creating the Product entity, persisting and flushing with the EntityManager.
Second, creating product component, but without knowledge about the real Product object, just having the id of the product:

```php
<?php
// run kernel..

// Product was persisted before in another class, during same kernel request

$em = ...

$productId = 'some-uuid';

$productReference = $em->getReference(Product::class, $productId);

$productComponent = new ProductComponent();
$productComponent->setProduct($productReference);

$em->persist($productComponent);
$em->flush();

$productRepository = $em->getRepository(Product::class);
$product = $productRepository->find($productId);

$components = $product->getProductComponents();
// $components will be empty ArrayCollection

// but what works:
$componentRepository = $em->getRepository(ProductComponent::class);
$components = $componentRepository->findBy(['product' => $productId]);

// $components will be found with the provided $productId

// end kernel..
```

When I am accessing now the `$productRepository` from a new kernel request, the returned product will have the component relations.

What's the reason for that? Is something missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `EntityManagerInterface::getReference` to assign a *proxy* `Product` entity to `ProductComponent` instead of a persisted `Product` entity. The actual persisted (in memory) `Product` entity is then not updated to have the newly added `ProductComponent` as being part of its collection (resulting in `$product->getProductComponents()` being empty).

Either [force the entity manager to update persisted entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456090/getreference-of-doctrine-entity-manager), or preferably *fetch* the desired `Product` entity using the entity repository:

```php
<?php
//...
$productRepository = $em->getRepository(Product::class);
$product = $productRepository->find($productId);
$productComponent->setProduct($product);
$em->persist($productComponent);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Already tried that, I've replaced the `getReference()` implementation against the `find` but nothing happens. The referenced object was already persisted and flushed before.